# remove duplicate GET value

Tags: php, .htaccess

im working with a custom cms that someone else did.
the problem is that when i add a redirect through htaccess, it always duplicates the first parameter (here named "perf") i tried adding other parameters as you can see on this line -> index.php?perf=$1&sub=$2

so, here is the htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on

#URL AMIGABLE UNIVERSAL

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?perf=$1&sub=$2&cat=$3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?perf=$1&sub=$2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?perf=$1
```

so the urls end looking like this -> http://www.test.com/questions?perf=questions i need it to be http://www.test.com/questions

is there a way to remove the duplicated part?

thanks,

Comment: Whats the URL going in, and what URL do you want your cms to see?

Comment: Are you sure the first parameter isn't an array? If it's an array it could be sending it twice

Comment: @castis sorry for not explaining myself well, the url that i need is this one -> http://www.test.com/questions